# BeautifulSoup search attributes-value

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to search in HTML documents for specific attribute values.
e.g.

```
<html> 
  <h2 itemprop="prio1">  TEXT PRIO 1 </h2>
  <span id="prio2"> TEXT PRIO 2 </span>
</html>
```

**I want to find all items with atrributes values beginning with "prio"**

I know that I can do something like:

```
soup.find_all(itemprop=re.compile('prio.*')) )
```

Or

```
soup.find_all(id=re.compile('prio.*')) )
```

**But what I am looking for is something like:**

```
soup.find_all(*=re.compile('prio.*')) )
```

Comment: Are you looking for literally all or just itemprop and id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off your regex is wrong, if you wanted to only find strings starting with *prio* you would prefix with `^`, as it is your regex would match prio anywhere in the string,  if you were going to search each attribute  you should just use *str.startswith*:

```
h = """<html>
  <h2 itemprop="prio1">  TEXT PRIO 1 </h2>
  <span id="prio2"> TEXT PRIO 2 </span>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(h, "lxml")


tags = soup.find_all(lambda t: any(a.startswith("prio") for a in t.attrs.values()))
```

If you just want to check for certain attributes:

```
tags = soup.find_all(lambda t: t.get("id","").startswith("prio") or t.get("itemprop","").startswith("prio"))
```

But if you wanted a more efficient solution you might want to look at [*lxml*](http://lxml.de/) which allows you to use wildcards:

```
from lxml import html

xml = html.fromstring(h)

tags = xml.xpath("//*[starts-with(@*,'prio')]")
print(tags)
```

Or just id an itemprop:

```
tags = xml.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'prio') or starts-with(@itemprop, 'prio')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way, but this works:

```
>>> soup.find_all(lambda element: any(re.search('prio.*', attr) for attr in element.attrs.values()))
[<h2 itemprop="prio1">  TEXT PRIO 1 </h2>, <span id="prio2"> TEXT PRIO 2 </span>]
```

In this case, you can access the element use `lambda` in `lambda element:`. And we search for `'prio.*'` use `re.search` in the `element.attrs.values()` list.

Then, we use `any()` on the result to see if there's an element which has an attribute and it's value starts with `'prio'`.

---

You can also use `str.startswith` here instead of  RegEx since you're just trying to check that attributes-value starts with `'prio'` or not, like below:

```
soup.find_all(lambda element: any(attr.startswith('prio') for attr in element.attrs.values())))
```

Comment: Is i possilbe that this syntax with lamba only works for BeautifulSoup 3 and not for bs4?
Because i get the Error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Comment: @info: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​I'm using BeautifulSoup 4 with Python 3.5, and this code works fine here. What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BeautifulSoup_test.py", line 40, in <module>
    soup.find_all(lambda element: any(attr.startswith('prio') for attr in element.attrs.values()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1259, in ...
  File "BeautifulSoup_test.py", line 40, in <genexpr>
    soup.find_all(lambda element: any(attr.startswith('prio') for attr in element.attrs.values()))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

Comment: btw: i also use bs4 and Python 3.5.1

Comment: it seems that this works for the simple example document but not for the real one.   .... i will try to find out why, and then write it here.

Comment: @info: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​Huh, that sounds strange​​. However,  you should always ask a question with a [mcve].